# Working with shape tracing in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, themes, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm in the early stages of trying to learn Orchard, and I'm still seem to be struggling with shape tracing in Orchard. I created content types, content parts and fields in orchard but i don't know how to display it with CSS classes so that it can work with my layout. I read the documents on orchard site and came to know about shape tracing but i really don't understand how can i add my css classes with the help of shape tracing. Please i may be missing on something or i can't find it properly please can someone provide me good links or tutorials so that i can break my head on it and understand how exactly this works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Shape tracing is not going to be especially helpful with CSS. What it does is help with template overriding. It might help you locate what template generated a specific piece of HTML so that you can then go and edit that template or override it in your theme (which means make a copy of the file in your theme so you can edit it without modifying a module). When you do that, you can add classes on any tag that's in there.